# Can I create a Finale file that has no bar lines?

Tags: finale

I am using Finale 2014 and I want to write a piano piece that has a given time signature (to give the pulse), but I don't want it to have any bar lines. Is there a way to remove all of them from the document?

Comment: @BobBroadley that's interesting. My question would have been 'in which program can I do that', but it would've been off topic. I'll see if I can do it on Sibelius

Comment: For  $DEITY$'s sake, *why*?  If you want a pulse, do it right.  If you don't want a pulse, then kill the time signature.    Or <wiseassmode> set the time signature to  46286028563725/4   and be done with it </wiseassmode>

Comment: @BobBroadley   He's not talking about staves.  He's asking about measure bars.

Comment: @BobBroadley correct; my mistake there. I don't want bar lines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use Finale extensively.  This is very easy.

1.) Select the region you want to edit.

2.) Right-click

3.) Go to "Barlines"

4.) Select "Invisible"

Boom. You're done.

Comment: If this applies to the whole document, just go to the Document menu, click Document Options > Barlines and untick the box that says "display all barlines".

Comment: @alephzero Correct, you can also accomplish it by ctrl + A and following my directions, or you can do it by creating and applying a staff style.